# How to increase $double.xmax in .Machine?

Tags: r

I want to calculate a big number.

My problem is that there is a limit.

So for example, if you run `factorial(170)` it returns: `[1] 7.257416e+306`.

But as soon as you want to calculate `factorial(171)`(or a bigger number) it returns `[1] Inf`.

That is because when you run `.Machine` you will see that

```
$double.xmax
[1] 1.797693e+308
```

So my question is, how can one make it bigger? For instance, can we make it to `1.797693e+500`?

Comment: You fundamentally can’t, the value is a property of the machine. To implement operations on very large numbers, you need to use a dedicated “bignum” library, e.g. [mpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, in base R; R can only do computations with 32-bit integers and 64-bit floating point values. You can use the `Rmpfr` package:

```
library(Rmpfr)
factorialMpfr(200)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  1246   bits 
## [1] 788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This value is "only" about 1e374, but we can easily go larger than that, e.g.

```
round(log10(factorialMpfr(400)))
869
```

However, there are some drawbacks to this: (1) computation is much slower; (2) it can be complicated to fit these results into an existing R workflow. People often find ways to do their computations on the log scale (you can compute log-factorial directly with the `lfactorial()` function)